# is it bad programming practice to call the same C# Property twice?

Tags: c#, java, methods, properties

To give an example, I have seen a lot of C# code such as the following:

```
XmlNode n = GetXmlNode();
String[] attributes = new String[n.Attributes.Count];
for (int x = 0; x < n.Attributes.Count; x++)
{
    //do something
}
```

Now, if this were java, we could write code similar to the following, but we would be guilty of calling the `getAttributes()` method twice, and if I am not mistaken there is a rule that says that instead of calling the same method multiple times, just declare a variable to hold a reference to the object returned by the method call and then use that variable as many times as necessary.

```
Node n = GetXmlNode();
String[] attributes = new String[n.getAttributes().getLength()];
for (int x = 0; x < n.getAttributes().getLength(); x++)
{
    //do something
}
```

But since a C# property is just a getter method and a setter method encapsulated in one type member, does it follow that the same rule should be observed?

Or does the rule not apply in this case because it is "safe" to assume that calls to C# properties and Java get methods in standard libraries just return references to fields rather than perform intense labor?

Comment: I wouldn't assume "references to fields" are what's happening here, but I'd certainly expect Java's JIT to identify and pull out the common variable.

Comment: In C# there are plenty of people who call `Count()` twice. Which is very different from `Count`.

Comment: @DaveShaw: It's not so different; it checks for `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: @SLaks, yeah, I meant "can be" not "is".

Comment: C# guidelines strongly encourage fast property getters. If a getter is more than a few times slower than a field fetch then it should be a method.

Comment: and I would be inclined to use linq rather than the loop in which case the question is moot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if there is some computation to get the value of property (*I consider doing some larger computation in property getter as bad practice, but you can't rely on that there is no such property*).

**The rule is:** In most of the cases you will be ok calling property multiple times. *...but who knows, who implemented that god damn performance killer property, just because it was available to do it in that way....*

**Good** - automatic property

```
public string MyValueProperty { get; set; }
```

is compiled to getter/setter like in java:

```
private string myValueProperty;
public string MyValueProperty
{
     get{
          return myValueProperty;
     }
     set{
          this.myValueProperty = value;
     }
}
```

*You will get little or no performance hit calling such property multiple times. It is similar to calling basic getter/setter methods in java.*

**Bad** - some computing is involved to get value of property

```
public string MyLongTimeToGetValueProperty
{
     get 
     { 
          var res = DoSomeComputation();
          return res;
     }
}
```

*It is better to avoid calling such properties multiple times. (Regardless that such kind of properties should be refactored to methods, because they behave like one)*

Answer (score 6):

Never store what you can compute. Storing what you can compute will lead to subtle bugs when the computed value changes but you're still using the stored value. Only disobey this rule if your program is slow and this is the biggest reason why it's slow (hint: it probably isn't)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider it premature optimisation.. depending on how big the collection it returns is.

If the collection is huge.. store the count once and use it from then on. Otherwise.. I wouldn't worry about it at all.

Answer (score 0):

When possible, use it the second time off of the assignment of the first time you access it.

In your example, you can code the following:

```
XmlNode n = GetXmlNode();
String[] attributes = new String[n.Attributes.Count];
for (int x = 0; x < attributes.GetUpperBound(0) + 1; x++)
{
     //do something
}
```